# Best Performing Jquery template plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, mobile, cordova

I'm working with phonegap to make web apps on mobile devices, and I'm very interested in Jquery templates, as I get facebook and youtube data with ajax and want to render them with a jquery template, so my needs are very simple .

I'm just very concerned with the template plugin performance since it will run on mobile devices, so it must be very effecient, and there are tons of template plugins out there, so which one is the best, performance wise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many searches and trials, I decided to use [DotJs](http://olado.github.io/doT/index.html) as it seems to be the fastest engine while still being very simple to use
I've tried [this benchmark](http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml-based-templating/413) on my Optimus Black (ICS Android Version) and it was the fastest engine with the highest Ops/Sec. (Higher is better)

Other engines i was thinking to use were

1. [Dust](http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/) (Linked in Version) as it has been used by linked in and is actively developed, but its size and features were huge regarding my simple needs
2. [Google Closure Templates](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/), Since they are used by google products, so i trusted the performance optimization as they are Battle Tested :) but i read that it isn't actively developed
3. [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) was another popular engine

Answer (score 2):

I recomend boostrap templates because from 3.0 version it's designed specifically for mobile and is very fast.

And they have a lot of templates avaiable:
http://goo.gl/p05xrE

Edit.

Mmmmm. ok sorry. Have you try to do it with underscore?

It can write your html with JSON data very nice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think you got me wrong . JQuery template plugins are used to render data into html templates. for example you can get facebook page posts as json and use a template plugin to shape them as you want, instead of looping in them and writing html codes hardcoded in your javascript

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Actually there are a lot of options and plugins that can do the task, but which is performing the best ? which is efficient on mobile devices with limited resources ?

Comment: In desktop enviroments i usually work with server tech behind like java, php or similar. In mobile enviroment i allways use underscore because it's very fast and stable and minified libary only have 14k.

Comment: Currently comparing between Dust, Handlebars, and Google Closure Templates